# How to make a global setTimeout and setInterval function with clearTimeout and clearInterval for all function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can we make a global setTimeout and setInterval function with respective clearTimeout and clearInterval for all functions and pass values to them?

actually the scenario is:

1: >8 functions with setInterval {fadeIn/fadeOut/togggle class/etc etc},

2: >4 functions with setTimeout {fadeIn/fadeOut/togggle class/etc etc},

3: only one function (setInterval / setTimeout) works at a time, after it finished their cycle, start another.

4: pass/send specific function values to them

like:

```
  function one(){ .....}
  function two(){ .....}
  function three(){ .....}
  function four(){ .....}
  function five(){ .....}
  ctimeout = setTimeout(function(){.....},time);
  sinterval = setInterval(function(){.....},time);
  clearTimeout(ctimeout);
  clearInterval(cinterval);
```

now, how to pass the functions to setInterval or setTimeout and how to make them dependable to other one {only one work at a time}

Comment: Sorry, but it is not clear what you are asking or what you want.  You've tagged your question with jQuery and refer to fadeIn and fadeOut, but you can do all those in jQuery without invoking any of your own timers (jQuery does that all for you).

Comment: I think we're all confused about what you want.  Are you wanting a queue that you can pass functions to that will execute them one at a time while waiting a certain period between runs?

Comment: looks like a menu.... I'll take 2 of the fades and 1/2 dozen timeouts to go

Comment: actually i want a queue, where all invoked function take place and do there appropriate process one by one until integrated setTimeout/setInterval timer is not expired.

Answer (score 0):

```
function_array=['one','two','three']

for(var i=0;i<=length.function_array;i++){
function delay(callback_clear){
  sinterval = setInterval(fun[i],time);
  callback_clear(sinterval);
 }
}

function callback_clear(param){
  clearInterval(param);
}
```